# Intramolecular protein residue contact map using biopython, KeyError: 'CA'

Tags: python, biopython, pdb

I am trying to identify amino acid residues in contact in the 3D protein structure. I am new to BioPython but found this helpful website http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/people/students/peter_cock/python/protein_contact_map/

Following their lead (which I will reproduce here for completion; Note, however, that I am using a different protein):

```
import Bio.PDB
import numpy as np

pdb_code = "1QHW"
pdb_filename = "1qhw.pdb" 

def calc_residue_dist(residue_one, residue_two) :
    """Returns the C-alpha distance between two residues"""
    diff_vector  = residue_one["CA"].coord - residue_two["CA"].coord
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(diff_vector * diff_vector))

def calc_dist_matrix(chain_one, chain_two) :
    """Returns a matrix of C-alpha distances between two chains"""
    answer = np.zeros((len(chain_one), len(chain_two)), np.float)
    for row, residue_one in enumerate(chain_one) :
        for col, residue_two in enumerate(chain_two) :
            answer[row, col] = calc_residue_dist(residue_one, residue_two)
    return answer

structure = Bio.PDB.PDBParser().get_structure(pdb_code, pdb_filename)
model = structure[0]

dist_matrix = calc_dist_matrix(model["A"], model["A"])
```

But when I run the above code, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-26-7239fb7ebe14>", line 4, in <module>
    dist_matrix = calc_dist_matrix(model["A"], model["A"])

  File "<ipython-input-3-730a11883f27>", line 15, in calc_dist_matrix
    answer[row, col] = calc_residue_dist(residue_one, residue_two)

  File "<ipython-input-3-730a11883f27>", line 6, in calc_residue_dist
    diff_vector  = residue_one["CA"].coord - residue_two["CA"].coord

  File "/Users/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Bio/PDB/Entity.py", line 39, in __getitem__
    return self.child_dict[id]

KeyError: 'CA'
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Looking at your error message there is no key named 'CA'.  Without knowing what the input files are it's difficult to help much more.  You may want to check that the dict being loaded is what you expect.

Comment: The input file can be found here: http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=1qhw. Top right -> "Download files" -> "PDB format"

Answer (score 2):

You have heteroatoms (water, ions, etc; anything that isn't an amino acid or nucleic acid) in your structure, remove them with:

```
for residue in chain:
    if residue.id[0] != ' ':
        chain.detach_child(residue.id)
```

This will remove them from your entire structure. You may want to modify if want to keep the heteroatoms for further analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that some of the elements in model["A"] are not amino acids and therefore do not contain "CA".

To get around this, I wrote a new function which returns only the amino acid residues:

```
from Bio.PDB import *
chain = model["A"]

def aa_residues(chain):
        aa_only = []
        for i in chain:
            if i.get_resname() in standard_aa_names:
                aa_only.append(i)
        return aa_only

    AA_1 = aa_residues(model["A"])
    dist_matrix = calc_dist_matrix(AA_1, AA_1)
```

Comment: ["However, in PDB files, a space can be part of an atom name. Often, calcium atoms are called 'CA..' in order to distinguish them from Cα atoms (which are called '.CA.'). In cases were stripping the spaces would create problems (ie. two atoms called 'CA' in the same residue) the spaces are kept."](https://biopython.org/wiki/The_Biopython_Structural_Bioinformatics_FAQ)  ??

Comment: You could probably use this provided function instead:

``from Bio.PDB.Polypeptide import is_aa``

Answer (score 0):

So I've been testing (bear in mind I know very little about Bio) and it looks like whatever is in you `1qhw.pdb` file is very different from the one in that example.

```
pdb_code = '1qhw'
structure = Bio.PDB.PDBParser().get_structure(pdb_code, pdb_filename)
model = structure[0]
```

next, to see what is in it, I did:

```
print(list(model))
```

Which gave me:

```
[<Chain id=A>]
```

exploring this, it appears the pdb file is a dict of dicts.  So, using this id,

```
test = model['A']
```

gives me the next dict.  This level is the level being passed to your function that is causing the error.  Printing this with:

```
print(list(test))
```

Gave me a huge list of the data inside, including lots of residues and related info.  But crucially, no `CA`.  Try using this to see whats inside and modify the line:

```
diff_vector  = residue_one["CA"].coord - residue_two["CA"].coord
```

to reflect what you are after, replacing `CA` where appropriate.
I hope this helps, its a little tricky to get much more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to obtain the contact map for a protein chain is to use the [`PdbParser`](http://www.conkit.org/en/latest/api/generated/conkit.io.PdbIO.html#conkit.io.PdbIO.PdbParser) shipped with [ConKit](http://www.conkit.org/en/latest/).

[ConKit](http://www.conkit.org/en/latest/) is a library specifically designed to work with predicted contacts but has the functionality to extract contacts from a PDB file:

```
>>> from conkit.io.PdbIO import PdbParser
>>> p = PdbParser()
>>> with open("1qhw.pdb", "r") as pdb_fhandle:
...     pdb = p.read(pdb_fhandle, f_id="1QHW", atom_type="CA")
>>> print(pdb)
ContactFile(id="1QHW_0" nmaps=1
```

This reads your PDB file into the `pdb` variable, which stores an internal [`ContactFile`](http://www.conkit.org/en/latest/api/core.html#conkit.core.ContactFile) hierarchy. In this example, two residues are considered to be in contact if the participating CA atoms are within 8Å of each other.

To access the information, you can then iterate through the [`ContactFile`](http://www.conkit.org/en/latest/api/core.html#conkit.core.ContactFile) and access each [`ContactMap`](http://www.conkit.org/en/latest/api/core.html#conkit.core.ContactMap), which in your case corresponds to  intra-molecular contacts for chain A.

```
>>> for cmap in pdb:
...     print(cmap)
ContactMap(id="A", ncontacts=1601)
```

If you would have more than one chain, there would be a [`ContactMap`](http://www.conkit.org/en/latest/api/core.html#conkit.core.ContactMap) for each chain, and additional ones for inter-molecular contacts between chains.

The [`ContactMap`](http://www.conkit.org/en/latest/api/core.html#conkit.core.ContactMap) for chain A contains 1601 contact pairs. You can access the [`Contact`](http://www.conkit.org/en/latest/api/core.html#conkit.core.Contact) instances in each [`ContactMap`](http://www.conkit.org/en/latest/api/core.html#conkit.core.ContactMap) by either iterating or indexing. Both work fine.

```
>>> print(cmap[0])
Contact(id="(26, 27)" res1="S" res1_chain="A" res1_seq=26 res2="T" res2_chain="A" res2_seq=27 raw_score=0.961895)
```

Each level in the hierarchy has various functions with which you could manipulate contact maps. Examples can be found [here](http://www.conkit.org/en/latest/examples.html).